# Clickable Checkerboard applet

Tags: java

currently trying to correct some errors (maybe due to my misunderstanding of some concepts) for a clickable checkerboard applet.

- using an array to indicate whether a square of the checkerboard was selected (1 = selected, 0 = not selected) with mouse click listener
- add a white border to the square if mouse clicked (selected), without border if clicked again, or stay with a border if I click another square
- attention was given to exclude coordinate (0, 0), as I don't want any square to be selected at the beginning, which was the case if I include (0, 0)

Errors:
- the array values changed but the repaint does not behaved as intended, border/ without border
- if I select a square next to another selected square, the selection of the other square disappears

Advices on how I can move forward with this would be much appreciated.

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseListener;

public class ClickableCheckerboard extends Checkerboard implements MouseListener {


    @Override
    public void init() {
        initSelectionRecord();
        addMouseListener(this);
    }

    private static int 
            selectedRow, selectedCol,       // row and col of checkerboard
            x, y;                        // coordinates of a mouse click

//  Selection state of each square of the Checkerboard board.
    private static int selectionRecord[][];   // 8 x 8 array (0 to 7, row x col), 0 = not selected, 1 = selected

//  Initialise selection state of each square of the Checkerboard board.
    public void initSelectionRecord() {
        int row, col;
        selectionRecord = new int[8][8];        // Allocate memory for the array, otherwise end up with NullPointerException
        for (row = 0; row < 8; row++) {
            for (col = 0; col < 8; col++) {
                selectionRecord[row][col] = 0;
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {

        x = e.getX();
        y = e.getY();
        selectedRow = getRow(y);
        selectedCol = getCol(x);

        if (selectedRow != -1 && selectedCol != -1) {
            repaint(selectedCol * 20, selectedRow * 20, 19, 19);
            repaint(0, 161, 300, 300);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
    }

    @Override
    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
    }


    /**
     * Returns the column of the checkerboard for an integer x coordinate.
     *
     * @param x
     * @return col if inside checkerboard, or -1 if outside checkerboard
     */
    public int getCol(int x) {
        int col = -1;
        if (x <= 160 && x != 0) {
            col = (int) (x / 20);
        } 
        return col;
    }

    /**
     * Returns the row of the checkerboard for an integer y coordinate.
     *
     * @param y
     * @return row if inside checkerboard, or -1 if outside checkerboard
     */
    public int getRow(int y) {
        int row = -1;
        if (y <= 160 && y != 0) {
            row = (int) (y / 20);
        } 
        return row;
    }


    /**
     * Returns the selection state of a square of the checkerboard
     *
     * @param row
     * @param col
     * @return i - 1 if selected, 0 if unselected, -1 if not applicable
     */
    public static int getSelectionRecord(int row, int col) {
        int i = -1;
        if (row < 8 && col < 8){
            i = selectionRecord[row][col];
        }
        return i;
    }

    /**
     * Select a square by adding a white border to it, or unselect it by clearing the border 
     *
     * @param row
     * @param col
     * @param g
     */
    public void toggleSelection(int row, int col, Graphics g) {

        int evenRow, evenCol, width, height;

        evenRow = row % 2;
        evenCol = col % 2;
        width = 19;
        height = 19;

        if (getSelectionRecord(row, col) == 0) {
            selectionRecord[row][col] = 1;
            g.setColor(Color.white);
            g.drawRect(col * 20 , row * 20 , width, height);
        } else if (getSelectionRecord(row, col) == 1) {
            selectionRecord[row][col] = 0;
            if (evenRow == 0 && evenCol == 0) {
                g.setColor(Color.red);
                g.fillRect(col * 20, row * 20, width, height);
            } else if (evenRow != 0 && evenCol != 0) {
                g.setColor(Color.red);
                g.fillRect(col * 20, row * 20, width, height);
            } else if (evenRow == 0 && evenCol != 0) {
                g.setColor(Color.black);
                g.fillRect(col * 20, row * 20, width, height);
            } else if (evenRow != 0 && evenCol == 0) {
                g.setColor(Color.black);
                g.fillRect(col * 20, row * 20, width, height);
            }
        } else if (getSelectionRecord(row, col) == -1) {

        }

    }


    public void paint(Graphics g) {

        super.paint(g);

        g.drawString("x is " + x + ". y is " + y + ".", 2, 180);

        if (x != 0 && y != 0 && x <=160 && y <= 160) {
            if (selectedRow != -1 && selectedCol != -1) {
                toggleSelection(selectedRow, selectedCol, g);  
            }
        }

        g.drawString("Selection state of toggled square is " + getSelectionRecord(selectedRow, selectedCol), 2, 200);

        int i, j;
        for (i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
            for (j = 0; j < 8; j++) {
                g.drawString(getSelectionRecord(i, j) + " ", (2 + j * 20), (220 + i * 20));
            }
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Is this code that was given to you by a teacher, or is this code you could freely change any part of? I would if possible change the code so that it was a bunch of JButtons laid out in a grid, and from there you could have an ActionListener attached to each, that then performs the border addition.

Comment: Thank you for your advice.  Does the JButton remain changed after I pressed it, as I would need it to stay in a 'pressed' state until I press it again to change it to 'unpressed' state.  I shall look into this.

Comment: You don't update the content of `selectionRecord` when a mouse click is detected, you only invoke a repaint.

Comment: The JButton could certainly keep the state changes. The main reason I suggested using that was that your code contains a lot of hard coded values that won't resize nicely when the Frame is resized (if this is something our applet will allow). It would however be very different when trying to design the appearance of the board. After re-reading your question numerous times, I'm unsure as to whether my idea is the best for you, so for now I would address the problem StephaneM noted.

Comment: Thank you to you both.  The resize consideration is very valid.  Also, I shall check the selectionRecord.